# I need to find the NON COMPLIANCE ports in device. using python 2.7.13

Tags: python-2.7

I need to find the NON compliance ports in Network device. I have taken the all ports in a list and compliance ports in a list, now simply i want to take the difference between those. below are the two outputs.

```
ALL_PORTS = [u'ge-3/0/34', u'ge-3/0/35', u'ge-3/0/36', u'ge-3/0/37', u'ge-3/0/30', u'ge-3/0/31', u'ge-3/0/32', u'ge-3/0/33', u'ge-3/0/38', u'ge-3/0/39', u'ge-0/0/13', u'ge-0/0/12', u'ge-0/0/11', u'ge-0/0/10', u'ge-0/0/17', u'ge-0/0/16', u'ge-0/0/15', u'ge-0/0/14', u'ge-0/0/19', u'ge-0/0/18', u'ge-3/0/41', u'ge-3/0/40', u'ge-3/0/43', u'ge-3/0/42', u'ge-2/0/19', u'ge-2/0/18', u'ge-3/0/47', u'ge-3/0/46', u'ge-2/0/15', u'ge-2/0/14', u'ge-2/0/17', u'ge-2/0/16', u'ge-2/0/11', u'ge-2/0/10', u'ge-2/0/13', u'ge-2/0/12', u'ge-1/0/47', u'ge-1/0/46', u'ge-1/0/45', u'ge-1/0/44', u'ge-1/0/43', u'ge-1/0/42', u'ge-3/0/23', u'ge-1/0/29', u'ge-1/0/28', u'ge-3/0/22', u'ge-1/0/25', u'ge-1/0/24', u'ge-1/0/27', u'ge-1/0/26', u'ge-1/0/21', u'ge-1/0/20', u'ge-1/0/23', u'ge-1/0/22', u'ge-3/0/20', u'ge-3/0/27', u'ge-3/0/26', u'ge-3/0/25', u'ge-3/0/24', u'ge-3/0/11', u'ge-1/0/38', u'ge-1/0/39', u'ge-1/0/36', u'ge-1/0/37', u'ge-1/0/34', u'ge-1/0/35', u'ge-1/0/32', u'ge-1/0/33', u'ge-1/0/30', u'ge-1/0/31', u'ge-2/0/33', u'ge-2/0/32', u'ge-2/0/31', u'ge-2/0/30', u'ge-2/0/37', u'ge-2/0/36', u'ge-2/0/35', u'ge-2/0/34', u'ge-2/0/39', u'ge-2/0/38', u'ge-2/0/24', u'ge-2/0/25', u'ge-2/0/26', u'ge-2/0/27', u'ge-2/0/20', u'ge-2/0/21', u'ge-2/0/22', u'ge-2/0/23', u'ge-2/0/28', u'ge-2/0/29', u'ge-3/0/18', u'ge-3/0/19', u'ge-1/1/3', u'ge-1/0/6', u'ge-1/0/7', u'ge-1/0/4', u'ge-1/0/5', u'ge-1/0/2', u'ge-1/0/3', u'ge-1/0/0', u'ge-1/0/1', u'ge-3/0/14', u'ge-1/0/8', u'ge-1/0/9', u'ge-1/0/14', u'ge-1/0/15', u'ge-1/0/16', u'ge-1/0/17', u'ge-1/0/10', u'ge-1/0/11', u'ge-1/0/12', u'ge-1/0/13', u'ge-1/0/18', u'ge-1/0/19', u'ge-3/0/13', u'ge-3/0/10', u'ge-0/0/40', u'ge-0/0/41', u'ge-0/0/42', u'ge-0/0/43', u'ge-0/0/44', u'ge-0/0/45', u'ge-0/0/46', u'ge-0/0/47', u'ge-3/0/4', u'ge-3/0/5', u'ge-3/0/6', u'ge-3/0/7', u'ge-3/0/0', u'ge-3/0/1', u'ge-3/0/2', u'ge-3/0/3', u'ge-3/0/8', u'ge-3/0/9', u'ge-0/0/7', u'ge-0/0/6', u'ge-0/0/5', u'ge-0/0/4', u'ge-0/0/3', u'ge-0/0/2', u'ge-0/0/1', u'ge-0/0/0', u'ge-3/0/16', u'ge-3/0/17', u'ge-1/0/41', u'ge-3/0/15', u'ge-3/0/12', u'ge-0/1/3', u'ge-0/0/9', u'ge-0/0/8', u'ge-3/0/21', u'ge-0/0/39', u'ge-0/0/38', u'ge-0/0/35', u'ge-0/0/34', u'ge-0/0/37', u'ge-0/0/36', u'ge-0/0/31', u'ge-0/0/30', u'ge-0/0/33', u'ge-0/0/32', u'ge-2/0/42', u'ge-2/0/43', u'ge-2/0/40', u'ge-2/0/41', u'ge-2/0/46', u'ge-2/0/47', u'ge-2/0/44', u'ge-2/0/45', u'ge-1/0/40', u'ge-2/0/5', u'ge-2/0/4', u'ge-2/0/7', u'ge-2/0/6', u'ge-2/0/1', u'ge-2/0/0', u'ge-2/0/3', u'ge-2/0/2', u'ge-3/0/29', u'ge-3/0/28', u'ge-2/0/9', u'ge-2/0/8', u'ge-0/0/28', u'ge-0/0/29', u'ge-0/0/26', u'ge-0/0/27', u'ge-0/0/24', u'ge-0/0/25', u'ge-0/0/22', u'ge-0/0/23', u'ge-0/0/20', u'ge-0/0/21', u'ge-3/0/45', u'ge-3/0/44']

COMPLIANCE_PORTS = [u'ge-3/0/45', u'ge-3/0/45', u'ge-0/0/19', u'ge-0/0/0,', u'ge-0/0/25,', u'ge-1/0/3,', u'ge-1/0/4,', u'ge-1/0/5,', u'ge-2/0/0,', u'ge-2/0/3,', u'ge-2/0/5,', u'ge-2/0/13,', u'ge-2/0/26,', u'ge-3/0/45', u'ge-0/0/27,', u'ge-0/0/29,', u'ge-0/0/43,', u'ge-0/0/44,', u'ge-0/0/45', u'ge-0/1/3', u'ge-0/1/3', u'ge-1/1/3', u'ge-1/1/3']

NONCOMPLIANCE_PORTS = list(set(ALL_PORTS) - set(COMPLIANCE_PORTS))
```

If i am doing the set difference the i am not getting the actual difference. Please help.

Comment: If I run this I get the difference between all ports and compliance ports - what is the error/output you are seeing and what did you expect to see?

Comment: I got my answer. It was my fault only.. Both interfaces having some difference with ",". Anyway thanks..